# How do I alter the content type form?

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a new content type in Drupal. I would like to customize the add/edit form for the node utilizing `hook_form_alter()`, but I'm not sure how to implement this hook. How can I implement and change the form with it?

Comment: In order to add / adjust the node edit form you need to use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and make your adjustments. You may also use [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) on the specific node edit form.